# How to repeatedly show variations on a plot

Tags: plotting, animation

I would like to show graphics repeatedly with changes in parameters. Neither of the following show anything.  Nor do they give an error message.

```
Do[Plot[y = Sqrt[(1/n) x], {x, 0, 1}], {n, 1, 5}]

For[n = 1, n < 6, n++, Plot[y = Sqrt[(1/n) x], {x, 0, 1}]]
```

These merely show the plot for n=1.

```
Do[Return[Plot[y = Sqrt[(1/n) x], {x, 0, 1}]], {n, 1, 5}]

Do[(Pause[1]; Return[Plot[y = Sqrt[(1/n) x], {x, 0, 1}]]), {n, 1, 5}]

For[n = 1, n < 6, n++, Return[Plot[y = Sqrt[(1/n) x], {x, 0, 1}]]]
```

(I tried Pauses in the others, to no avail.)

How do I make this work?

Comment: In addition to the great answers below I would also recommend taking a look at this URL. All those free apps are made with Mathematica and you can download the source code and see how it works. **http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/search.html?query=parabola**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You probably want `Animate`, if your intent is to show the plot varying for different `n`. Here's an example:

```
Animate[Plot[Sqrt[(1/n) x], {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {All, {0, 1}}], {n, 1, 5}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

What you use depends on what you are looking for.

But, first things first, neither [`Do`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Do.html) nor [`For`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/For.html) will work, as you found out, as both explicitly only return a value (a plot is considered a value) if `Return` is used. (See below for ways to get `For` and `Do` to work.) Unfortunately, [`Return`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Return.html) breaks out of the `For` and `Do` immediately, so only the `n==1` iteration is evaluated. So, it pays to use a function that is built for constructing lists rather than `Do` or `For`.

The simplest method of plotting a sequence of plots is as [Artes](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2056/52) said: use `Table`. Between the two forms he proposes, I prefer the second form as it plots the functions on the same graph, but the first form is more akin to what you were attempting. As an alternative, you could `Map` `Plot` over the values of `n`

```
Plot[Sqrt[(1/#) x], {x, 0, 1}]& /@ Range[1,5]
```

or,

```
Plot[ Evaluate[ Sqrt[(1/#) x]& /@ Range[1,5] ], {x, 0, 1}]
```

Additionally, you should look at [`Manipulate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Manipulate.html) which allows you to manipulate the plot directly.

```
Manipulate[Plot[Sqrt[x/n], {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {0, 1}], {n, 1, 5}]
```

gives

[image]

Note the use of [`PlotRange`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PlotRange.html) which fixes the y-axis to a specific range. If it is not present, the plot looks identical, but the y-axis changes in scale. Lastly, there's animating the whole thing, as [R.M suggested](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2055/52).

---

As an aside, the above code is what one would usually use if they want to create a new `List` of objects. But, expressions can be constructed where both `Do` and `For` will in effect create a new `List`. The secret is to use [`Append`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Append.html) or [`AppendTo`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/AppendTo.html) on a `List` that already exists, or possibly using [`Reap`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Reap.html) and [`Sow`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Sow.html).

Using your code for `Do` as an example,

```
 lst = {};
 Do[AppendTo[lst, Plot[Sqrt[(1/n) x] , {x, 0, 1}]], {n, 1, 5}]
```

or, more verbosely

```
 lst = {};
 Do[lst = Append[lst, Plot[Sqrt[(1/n) x], {x, 0, 1}]], {n, 1, 5}]
```

and, most "simply"

```
 Reap[Do[Sow[Plot[Sqrt[(1/n) x], {x, 0, 1}]], {n, 1, 5}]][[2]]
```

Comment: Good answer explaining _why_ OP's code doesn't work. The rest of us focused on the final objective and neglected the root of the OP's confusion :)

Answer (score 7):

Here is the really quick way: In your first `Do` loop, you can force `Plot` to create output by adding `Print` in front of it:

```
Do[Print@Plot[Sqrt[(1/n) x], {x, 0, 1}], {n, 1, 5}]
```

Now you decide you want to animate the result just to get an overview of the plots, but don't want to redo the loop. To do that, select all the output graphics by clicking the cell bracket containing them, then press `Comand-y` (or `Control-y` depending on the platform). This is also available under the menu `Graphics > Rendering > Animate selected graphics`.

This is what you do to just show the variations in a plot, as you asked. It's not the best choice if you want to permanently create a movie, of course.

**Edit for version 10**

As noted in the comment, the menu item for animating a selected cell group isn't present in version 10 anymore. Therefore, if you want a quick way to create an animation of an arbitrary selection of cells, it has to be implemented using notebook manipulation. This may still sometimes be nice to have, instead of being forced to construct the list of frames by manual copy-pasting.

So I made a button for it:

```
CreatePalette[{
   Button["Animate Selection",
    With[{l = 
       ToExpression@
        Cases[NotebookRead[InputNotebook[]], 
         BoxData[z_] :> z, Infinity]},
     CreateDocument[ListAnimate[l], WindowSize -> All]]]}];
```

This palette lets you take the same output as generated in the example above, and convert it to a movie in a new window by pressing the "Animate Selection" button.

Comment: Is this still possible in Mathematica 10.x?

Comment: I have no "Rendering" submenu in my Graphics menu, and Control-y is not doing anything (Windows 7, Mathematica v10.2). I also could not find a FrontEnd Token to trigger this.

Comment: @GustavoDelfino I've updated my answer to get a similar functionality in newer versions of *Mathematica*.

Comment: Thank you. That is a nice palette button!

Answer (score 4):

Try one of the following:

```
Table[ Plot[ Sqrt[(1/n) x], {x, 0, 1}], {n, 1, 5}]
```

or

```
 Plot[ Evaluate@Table[ Tooltip@Sqrt[(1/n) x], {n, 1, 5}], {x, 0, 1}]
```

The first method yields five different plots (as you seemed to expect; you don't need to set`y = Sqrt[(1/n) x]` in `Plot` since you don't make any use of it), while the latter visalizes differences between functions in one plot, where `Tooltip` makes show formulas of given functions.

**Edit**

One could follow this way further to make a visualization a bit more friendly like in [R.M.'s answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2054/how-to-repeatedly-show-variations-on-a-plot/2055#2055) :

```
Animate[
 Show[{Plot[Sqrt[x/k], {x, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> Thick], 
       Plot[Evaluate@Table[Sqrt[x/n], {n, 1, 5}],
            {x, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> Thick]}, 
       PlotRange -> {0, 1}], {k, 1, 5}]
```

[image]