# How to read data file quickly?

Tags: performance-tuning, import, data-format

I have a tab separated value file with 10 million rows each of which has three tab separated values.  The first value is a string, the second an integer, and the third another string.  How to read efficiently (in terms of timing and memory footprint) the $n^{th}$ to $(n+100)^{th}$ rows of the file into Mathematica as

```
{
    {_String, _Integer, _String},
    ...
}
```

?

Comment: For a more generic type of answer on this problem read my solution [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/107666)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

For a one-off read you can [`Skip`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Skip.html) a number of records:

```
str = OpenRead["test.tsv"];
Skip[str, Record, n - 1];
data = ReadList[str, {Record, Number, Record}, 100, RecordSeparators -> {"\t", "\n"}];
Close[str];
```

If you will be reading from the same file many times, it may be worth building an index you can use with [`SetStreamPosition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SetStreamPosition.html)

```
str = OpenRead["test.tsv"];
index = Table[pos = StreamPosition[str]; Skip[str, Record]; pos, {100000}];

readlines[n_, m_] := Block[{},
SetStreamPosition[str, index[[n]]];
ReadList[str, {Record, Number, Record}, m, RecordSeparators -> {"\t", "\n"}]]

data = readlines[50000,100]
```

On my PC building the index took about half a second for 10^5 rows in the file, assuming it scales linearly this would be about a minute for 10^7 rows. So this is only worth doing if you are going to be doing a *lot* of reads.

Comment: Since this is going to be used on a very large file, it is very likely that at some point `Abort` will be called while the file is being `Read`. So, it needs to be wrapped in a `CheckAbort` so that you can ensure that you close the stream if an `Abort` occurs. Here's a [cautionary tale](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/XcK_fkeTQY0/discussion) of what happens if too many `Streams` are left open. Also, an error is thrown if you attempt to open a file with an existing `Stream`.

Comment: +1 - Nice use of streams. You can build index about 5-6 times faster (according to my benchmarks) with this function: `buildIndex[file_] :=
  With[{bytes = BinaryReadList[file]}, Prepend[#, 0] &[
   Most@Flatten[(SparseArray[#, Length[#], 1] & @Unitize[bytes - 10])["NonzeroPositions"]] - 1]]`, when there is enough memory to hold all file's contents in RAM at once. A speed - memory tradeoff.

Comment: What if the rows are of form `_String _Integer _String _Integer`?

Comment: @Leonid: I'm sure you are aware of it but probably not every other reader: you could build the index with `BinaryReadList` as you suggested even if the file content doesn't fit in RAM by handling the content in chunks. That would let you take control over speed vs. memory in even more detail...

Comment: @AlbertRetey Thanks, a very good point!

Comment: @MaThEmAtika: you would have to use `{Record, Number, Record, Number}` in the `ReadList` expression.

Comment: @Simon Woods,  and `RecordSeparators -> {"\t", "\n"}` will work with it!?

Comment: @MaThEmAtika, it should do. Is it not working for you?

Comment: @SimonWoods, I'm trying to read a large file that has periodic repetition of useful and useless data. So the first 7 lines are useless while the next say 1000 lines are useful, then the next 7 lines are useless etc. So I want to just store only the useful data into a variable. Can your answer here be adapted to handle this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10):

Here is a solution for Linux/( ? Mac ? ) uses, or Windows users with a Linux toolkit.

To read line 23681 to 23781, use the following variants of `head` and `tail`.

```
data=Import["!head -23781 /tmp/data.txt | tail -n 100", "Text"];
```

Comment: Any idea how to make this also work on Windows?

Comment: @Problemania Reports say that this http://sourceforge.net/projects/unxutils/ or `msysgit` will give you unix command line utils in the windows environment.

Comment: I confirm that this works on Mac too.

Comment: @image_doctor can you also use `grep`? I tried replacing `!head` with `grep `, it doesn't work, any idea?

Answer (score 4):

You can use set stream position which sets the current point in an open stream. Then you can use Read which reads one expression from an input stream, and returns the expression with byte, character,  expression, Number, Real, String or Word options. Something like:

**Edit 1** with ReadList

```
n = 4;
str = OpenRead["data.txt"];
Skip[str, Record, n - 1]
ReadList[str, {Word, Number, Word}, 100]
Close[str];
```

**Edit 2** with Read and Loop no abort check

```
data = {};
n = 4;
str = OpenRead["data.txt"];
Skip[str, Record, n - 1]
For[i = 0, i < 100, i++,
 {a, b, c} = Read[str, {Word, Number, Word}];
 data = Append[data, {a, b, c}];
 ]
Close[str];
data
```

**Edit 2** with Read and Loop with abort check

```
data = {};
n = 4;
str = OpenRead["data.txt"];
Skip[str, Record, n - 1]
For[i = 0, i < 100, i++, CheckAbort[Module[{a, b, c},
   {a, b, c} = Read[str, {Word, Number, Word}];
   data = Append[data, {a, b, c}];
   ], Close[str]]]
Close[str];
data
```

Comment: That gives a `Read::readn: Invalid real number found when reading from ...` error.

Comment: `SetStreamPosition[str, n]` doesn't seem to be correct. It shouldn't be `n`.  `n` is the row index.  But `SetStreamPosition` doesn't seem to operate on `rows`.

Comment: `For` won't work as written, see this [question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2054/52) and my [answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2059/52). Also, `String` captures the entire line, `Word` should be used instead. Lastly, as this is a large file, the `For` loop should be wrapped in a `CheckAbort` to ensure that the `Stream` is closed properly. I'd use the `OpenAndRead` function I define [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4176381/198315).

Comment: @ rcollyer Thanks for the links. But, some how they don't point to the right page. I found via search and it was useful.

Comment: @ MaThEmAtika, I wrote them lack of time in order to give you some possible paths and functions.