# Plot data from txt file?

Tags: plotting, import

I have data in file.txt which can be expressed by 20000x11 matrix. I do not want to import all of these data. How can I plot graph of the column 1 & column 4?

Comment: You will anyway have to import some data. If the built-in `Import` is too slow for you, you can try setting up a custom importer function similarly to how it was done [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5179/how-to-read-data-file-quickly).

Answer (score 24):

If the data are comma-delimited and saved as `myfile.txt` then

```
data =Import["C:\\Users\\md\\Desktop\\myfile.txt", {"Data",  {All}, {1, 3}}];
```

imports columns 1 and 3, giving:

```
(*{{"a1", "a3"}, {"b1", "b3"}, {"c1", "c3"}, {"d1", "d3"}}*)
```

For comparison,

```
Import["C:\\Users\\md\\Desktop\\myfile.txt", {"Data"}]
```

gives

```
(*{{"a1", "a2", "a3", "a4", "a5"}, {"b1", "b2", "b3", "b4", 
  "b5"}, {"c1", "c2", "c3", "c4", "c5"}, {"d1", "d2", "d3", "d4", 
  "d5"}} *)
```

More information may be found [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/howto/ImportASpreadsheet.html) ("How to Import a Spreadsheet")

Comment: I had forgotten about sub-elements. +1

Comment: What if it's space delimited? Are there options or do I have to convert my data file?

Comment: @BruceConnor Good question. As far as I can see, space delimited still works `Import["C:\\Users\\md\\Desktop\\myfileSpace.txt", {"Data", {All}, {1, 
   3}}]`, for example. It would be good to know if you have got it to work.

Comment: Yes, I got it to work.

Comment: What if I want to plot the second column in this data? how can i do that?

Comment: @suzy.  I am not sure I have fully understood your question. However... If, say, data =  {{0, 0, 0}, {1, 20, 100}, {2, 40, 200}, {3, 60, 300}} and I would like to plot column 1 versus colum 2 AND (on the same graph) column 1 versus columm 3, I could do that as follows: `ListLinePlot[
 Transpose /@ {{data[[All, 1]], data[[All, 3]]}, {data[[All, 1]], 
    data[[All, 2]]}}, PlotMarkers -> Automatic, 
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Green}]`. Perhaps you were thinking of something different to ListLinePlot?

Answer (score 7):

If the file is very large and importing it takes too much memory, you can use external tools to cut the columns you are interested in.  You can often call these tools directly from Mathematica, for example

```
ReadList["!awk '{print $1, $4}' file.txt", {Number, Number}]
```

This will use [awk](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Getting-Started) to cut columns 1 and 4.  [`ReadList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ReadList.html), with an explicit specification of the type of each column, is typically going to be faster and more memory efficient than `Import`.

This approach can be significantly faster than `Import["file.txt", "Table"][[All, {1,4}]]` if the file is large enough, and especially if it contains heterogeneous data which `Import` must auto-detect.

Comment: Assuming *nix environment? Nice to see awk in use - been a while :) +1 for ! form which i didn't know about.

Comment: @SEngstrom Yes, assuming Unix for the `'`-quoting to work.  I'm not sure how to specify an awk program on the command line on Windows---I think it should be `"`-quoted.  It should work on Windows too (if awk is installed and in the path).  I used Windows until recently. The `!`-syntax works in practically all importing functions and it's quite useful

Answer (score 3):

```
data=Import["myFile","Table"][[All,{1,4}]];
ListPlot@data
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that does not adhere to the OPs request to not import all of the data.

Comment: @rcollyer I can't disagree with you :) But I sense some ambiguity in the original question. The data isn't too large, it should fit in memory with ease and may well produce the result the OP wanted. I'll happily withdraw the answer if it isn't what is required.

Comment: Let's see what they say. If it is on a memory constrained machine, then sure, but as you said, it is easily loadable in memory. Rough estimate, with 64 bit (8 byte) real numbers: 1.7 MB. Right. +1

Comment: @rcollyer that's what I thought, no problem, we'll leave it up to to them:)