# Simple manipulation of imported data

Tags: list-manipulation

I am importing 2 columns of numeric data from a data file in the way defined in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5921/4788):

```
data = Import["C:\\Users\\md\\Desktop\\myfile.txt", {"Data",  {All}, {1, 3}}];
```

These are my `x` and `y` values for a graph I'm plotting with `ListPlot`.

But I also need to apply some simple manipulations to the `y` values (the second column), like multiplying by 2 or taking the absolute value.

From the documentation I know it's possible by defining a function which takes a pair of values as arguments and then applying that function to `data` with `Map`, but that seems awfully troublesome when all I want is to multiply the `y` column by 2.

Is there a quick and simple way to do that?

*This could either be done while importing, after importing, or while plotting, either way is fine.*
*I also don't care about which format I'm importing to, as long as it supports several thousand points.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define some 2 dimensional data:

```
data = RandomInteger[{1, 2}, {10, 2}]
```

> {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {2, 2}, {2, 1}, {2, 1}, {2, 1}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}, {1, 
>     2}, {1, 2}}

**Tranpose**

Transpose your 2D pairs of data so it is now too long lists,  multiply the two lists by the factors you want ( here: 1 and 2 )  and then transpose the two long lists back again into 2D pairs of data.

```
Transpose@data {1, 2} // Transpose
```

> {{1, 2}, {2, 4}, {2, 4}, {2, 2}, {2, 2}, {2, 2}, {2, 2}, {2, 4}, {1, 
>     4}, {1, 4}}

**Map**

You can achieve  this in less characters with `Map` or short form `/@` and a pure function like so:

```
{1,2} # & /@data
```

> {{1, 2}, {2, 4}, {2, 4}, {2, 2}, {2, 2}, {2, 2}, {2, 2}, {2, 4}, {1, 
>     4}, {1, 4}}

The extent of the pure function is defined by the terminating `&` and its parameter(s) are accessed using `#` or `#n` for the nth parameter.

Here the `#` represents the pure function's first parameter which in this case is provided my `Map` and is a top level element of the list of data, a 2D point, {x,y}.

Mathematica automatically takes care of the list multiplication so that expressions of the following form are handled correctly:

```
{1, 2}  {a, b}
```

> {a, 2 b}

Answer (score 2):

Since you're also asking how to take the absolute value of the data in the second column, I provide you this solution that uses `Map`:

```
data = RandomInteger[{-2, 2}, {10, 2}]
```

> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {1, 1}, {-2, -2}, {1, 2}, {-1, 
>     1}, {2, -1}, {-2, -2}, {0, -2}}

```
Map[{#[[1]], Abs[#[[2]]]} &, data]
```

> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {1, 1}, {-2, 2}, {1, 2}, {-1, 1}, {2, 
>     1}, {-2, 2}, {0, 2}}

Or with a shorter notation:

```
{#[[1]], Abs[#[[2]]]} & /@ data
```

> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {1, 1}, {-2, 2}, {1, 2}, {-1, 1}, {2, 
>     1}, {-2, 2}, {0, 2}}