# Plotting points from file

Tags: plotting

How can I plot points (for example `{{1 , 1}, {3 , 7}, {5 , 5}}`) having as an input a file which contains the points coordinates ?

And is there any way to draw a line between 2 consecutive points?

Comment: Look up `Import[]` and `Line[]`.

Comment: related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5916/1089

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Import coordinates:

```
data = Import["file.txt", "CSV"]
```

Out:

```
{{1,1}, {3,7}, {5,5}}
```

Plot the points:

```
ListLinePlot[data]
```

Most basic examples like this can be easily found in the mathematica documentation. Hit F1 for help and look up for `Import`, `ListPlot`, `ListLinePlot`,... There are also helpful tutorials like `tutorial/ImportingAndExportingData`.

**Import Formats**

There are many ways to store data in files and import them.
You can use various `$ImportFormats`.

If you have a file containing comma seperated data like this

```
1, 1
3, 7
5, 5
```

use `"CSV"` for the import format.

In:

```
Import["file.txt", "CSV"]
```

Out:

```
{{1,1}, {3,7}, {5,5}}
```

This is how the data would be stored if you use the `"List"` import format:

```
{1, 1}
{3, 7}
{5, 5}
```

In:

```
Import["file.txt", "List"]
```

Out:

```
{{1,1}, {3,7}, {5,5}}
```

The data could also be seperated by tabs `"\t"`:

```
1    10
3    7
5    5
```

then use `"Table"` for importing the data:

In:

```
Import["file.txt", "Table"]
```

Out:

```
{{1,1}, {3,7}, {5,5}}
```

**Relation to Export**

`Export` uses the same formats for writing a file with data.

In:

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
data = {{1,1}, {3,7}, {5,5}};
Export["file.txt", data, "Table"];
Import["file.txt", "Table"]
```

Out:

```
{{1,1}, {3,7}, {5,5}}
```

**Visualization**

Use `ListLinePlot` if you want lines between the datapoints.

```
ListLinePlot[data]
```

[image]

With `Joined -> True` you can use `ListPlot` instead:

```
ListPlot[data, Joined -> True]
```

[image: ListPlot with Option Joined]

Show `ListLinePlot` and `ListPlot` together for better visualization:

```
Show[{ListLinePlot[data], 
ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, PointSize[.02]]]}]
```

[image: Show ListLinePlot and ListPlot together]

Comment: How should I write the coordinates in the file? What is `file.txt` containing?

Comment: Error: `Import::noelem: The Import element "Table" is not present when importing as Text.`

Comment: Table needed to be given as a `String`, i edited that just now. You can also try `"List"`, `"CSV"`, or any other `ImportFormat` instead of `"Table"`

Comment: @Abbey See my last edits for potential improvements and more information.