# Excluding Specific Rows Using Import[...]

Tags: import, data, csv-format, row

As the question states, I'm trying to import a `.csv` file but I would like to exclude certain rows (points which I know are bad data).

This is easy when the points are at the end I simply use something like:

```
  Data = Import["\\\\MyLocation\\MyFolder\\Myfile.csv"][[Range[N],{1,2}]];
```

Where `Range[N]` is where I want to stop importing and `{1,2}` are the columns I want. However I am unsure how to exclude points which are in the middle of the data set.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In fact `Import` has nothing to do with your approch, as you `Import` the whole file and then take a `Part` of it... take a look at `Part`,`Span` and `Drop` which will come in very handy for such tasks.

Comment: You should avoid using capitalized variables because they might conflict with built-ins, such as `N,E,D,...`. `N` - which you used - is already defined.

Comment: Thanks, I do try to! It is a habbit from more conventional coding where I use Camel-Casing (e.g. MyVariableName)

Comment: Is there a way to escape reserved characters for use in such names?

Comment: Just start with lowercase letters, e.g. `myVariableName`, `myFun[x]:=...`. For one letters variables, just use the uncapitalized version.

Comment: Also: if you want someone to be notified on SE when you respond to a comment or so, you have to start your comment with "@username" - otherwise it is very unlikely that the respective person will realize your comment.

Comment: @Lukas Ahhh! I tired this but had a space between @ and the username so nothing happened! Thanks for the tips!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments to your question, you just `Import` the whole data and then manipulate it afterwards. This is (I believe) a very transparent way to achieve the end result that you want and also illustrates why you should not use an "advanced" `Import`:

Let's produce some sample `data`

```
dim = 100;
data = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {dim, 3}];
Export[NotebookDirectory[] <> "dummy.dat", data, "Table"];
ClearAll[data];
```

of which we want to exclude certain rows:

```
exclude = RandomInteger[{1, dim}, 8];
wanted = DeleteCases[Range[dim], Alternatives @@ exclude];
```

Of course, if you do just `Import` your data, say into the variable `import`, then `dim=First@Dimensions@import`. Now let's compare the two approaches:

**Import everything and manipulate afterwards:**

```
First@AbsoluteTiming[
  data = Import[NotebookDirectory[] <> "dummy.dat", "Table"];
  correctedData = data[[wanted]];]
(* 0.023810 *)
```

**Import only the wanted rows:**

```
First@AbsoluteTiming[correctedImport = Import[NotebookDirectory[] <> "dummy.dat", {"Data", wanted}];]
(* 0.050041 *)
```

Note that the latter uses the built-in functionality of [`Import`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Import.html)

> `Import["file",elements]`: imports the specified elements from a file.

Now, we verify that both are the same:

```
correctedData == correctedImport
(* True *)
```

So, concluding, it is probably only useful to import specified elements if you would run into memory issues otherwise. If there are no limitations due to ressources, importing everything and manipulating afterwards is faster.

Comment: Thank you very much Lukas! The explanation was also very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

What follows is a variation on a [previous answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5921/106)

To exclude row 4 from comma-delimited data:

```
dataGood = Flatten[#, 1] & @(Import["/path/to/myfile.txt",{"Data", #, {All}}]
  & /@ {Range[3], Range[5, 6]});
```

and

```
dataGood // TableForm
```

> [image: Good Data - point excluded]

For comparison:

```
dataAll = Import["/path/to/myfile.txt", {"Data", {All}, {All}}];
dataAll // TableForm
```

> [image: All data points with no exclusions]

Comment: I have just updated my answer. It should be mentioned that timings of this selective approach are pretty bad compared to just importing everything and manipulating afterwards.

Comment: @Lukas. The OP specifically asks to exclude data which are known to be bad.  By excluding a row or rows, you may be excluding MB of data.

Comment: Hi TomD, thanks for answering, I like the simplicity of this solution. It also builds/extends upon what I already know. Thanks!

Comment: @TomD That is of course true. However, unless one works with data files on the order of a few GB, I do not believe there is any advantage to preselect rows (just because it appears to be way slower). But you're right that this is for sure important, if operating at the limits of one's ressources.