# Reading a specified line number from a text file

Tags: streams

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to read data file quickly?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5179/how-to-read-data-file-quickly)

I have a huge text file (~500 MB).  The file is too large to `Import` into Mathematica, although I can read it in Emacs.

Is there a way to tell Mathematica to `Read` in only line number 23681 (where lines are delimited by `"\n"` and `"\r"`, in the typical way, I think)?  For example, suppose that I have:

```
str = OpenRead["test.txt"];
```

For a text file, `StreamPosition` and `SetStreamPosition` seems to refer to the character number, not the line number.  Is there any way to change this?  Thank you for your time.

Comment: Related [question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5179/how-to-read-data-file-quickly/)

Comment: I'd say it's a dup