# Read and filter a text file without importing

Tags: import, data, data-acquisition

I have a large text file of a million sections. Each section contains A lines of header and B lines of numeric data.
I want to read the first and last line of B from each section (to have a list of 2 x million lines at the end).
`Import` doesn't work since my file is too big to be read into memory.
Is there a command like scan and filter for this?

Comment: You may try for example `SetStreamPosition[]`, but ... why don't you just preprocess the file with any capable language for text processing (AWK, perl, sed, whatever)

Comment: Have a look at [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15206/reading-periodic-elements-from-a-large-file/). There are a number of solutions shown there, which you might be able to adopt to your situation. All of them will however require to write some custom code.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16048/how-do-you-deal-with-very-large-datasets-in-mathematica). The link is certainly relevant to the current question.

Comment: Was my answer [useful](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/faq#howtoask) to you?

Answer (score 8):

You're looking for [`Skip`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Skip.html).  This does not check for an [`EndOfFile`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/EndOfFile.html) condition, and should use something like [`BlockStream`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1604/52) to handle aborts, but the following should work:

```
strm = OpenRead["filename"];

(* Repeat the following until done *)

Skip[strm, String, A];    
AppendTo[ results, Read[strm, String]]

(* 
  String just gets the entire line. If the number of elements is 
  constant for each row, then it can be replaced in the Read by   
  ConstantArray[String, numels]~Join~{String}. 
*)

Skip[strm, String, B - 2];
AppendTo[ results, Read[strm, String]]

(* close the stream *)
Close[ strm ];
```