# What's the most efficient way to load a very large dispatch table?

Tags: performance-tuning, data

This question is possibly related to [this topic](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16048/how-do-you-deal-with-very-large-datasets-in-mathematica), although I think I have something a little more specific in mind. Recently I've been working with dispatch tables for a project, since it seemed like a much more optimized way of implementing replacement rules. I haven't had many problems in actually *creating* the table and saving it (it is roughly ~1 GB of a plain text file).

However, I'd now like to use the dispatch table in a different notebook. It appears that just calling `Get["myDispatch"]` is extremely slow and eats up memory. I've experimented with using `.mx` files created by `DumpSave` instead, but to no avail (the files created are roughly of the same size, and still crash my computer trying to load).

Is it possible to efficiently load a dispatch table, or should I think about other ways to store my replacement rules?

Comment: What makes it so large? Are the rules themselves large expressions or is it a huge number of simple rules?

Comment: I would say it's mostly a huge number of simple rules. They take the form `x[{n1,n2,...,n10}]->` a number, but there are lots of rules because there's essentially a rule for each permutation of the list `{n1,n2,...,n10}`. I'm simplifying it a bit, but the number of associations grows combinatorially with the size of the lists, and I'm considering many lists of different length.

Comment: What happens if you use `Export[“some/path“,Compress@mydispatch,“String“]` and use the appropriate `Uncompress@Import[...]` to load it?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - that does seem a little faster than before. I actually ended up getting the most mileage by just not memoizing values that I didn't need, following [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19536/how-to-clear-parts-of-a-memoized-function) helpful answer, if anyone ever stumbles upon this question in the future.